# Update the values in database when open the image

Tags: php, api, .htaccess, email, gmail

I need some help with finding a way how I can update the values in the database when I open the email. I have got a problem with viewing the image and update the values in the database via redirect by using htaccess as gmail have blocked it when I am using signature.gif?id=123&etc=4567890 in the img tag.

Example:

```
<img src="http://example.com/track/Images/signature.gif?id=303&amp;etc=1572969471" style="width:0;max-height:0;overflow:hidden">
```

However, when I try this:

```
<img src="https://my-email-signature.link/signature.gif?u=579708&amp;e=73765037&amp;v=8d04aadd0a095e1e07175b0ae0f874b95a1308c4efffc3e1d4c0644d884970f1" style="width:0;max-height:0;overflow:hidden">
```

It works fine. It will view the image and update the values in the database in number of times in each time when I open the email. I have opened the url and it show the image. I don't know how they display the image and update the values in the database when the email is opened.

Do you know how I can update the values in the database when I open and view the image?

Do I need to use API to do that or what?

Thank you.

Comment: *"gmail have blocked it when I am using signature.gif?id=123&etc=4567890"* - Which makes perfect sense since hackers have a way to make different extensions act like another and cause potential harm. So, why the `.gif` extension with the GET `? ` parameter?

Comment: @Funk Forty Niner I understand that, but I am not hacking gmail as I just want to do the email tracker to see who have open my emails and who have not. Do you know how I can open the image and update the value in the database? any idea how i could do this?

Comment: You know that, and I know that, but Google doesn't ;-) What I suggest you try is using a regular GET parameter and checking if the user clicked the link, just like email/update verifycations are done.

Comment: I know what you mean but what about when the user is open the email and did not clicked the link? I need the user to open my email so I can see who have open my emails.

Comment: I have testing on yahoo, aol, hotmail..etc it all works fine but not on gmail as they are the problem.

Comment: We can't control how Gmail acts/reacts. All we can do is to try and fool it by using different methods. You'd basically do what you're doing now but using `?` instead of `&amp;` which could trigger an alarm on their side because you're trying to mask a character by using its equivalent in another fashion. By using `if(isset($_GET['key']) && !empty($_GET['key'])){...}` could be a way to go about it and adding to it with another array key. In any which way, they have to click the link you've provided them with.

Comment: Apart from all that, just asking: you _are_ aware that many people have deactivated the html visualization of emails for obvious reasons (security), so what you count is actually _not_ what you want to count?